# EF Navigation Properties not working?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a Card class:

```
public class Card
{
    public Card(){}

    [Key]
    [Required]
    public virtual int CardId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("StageId")]
    public virtual Stage Stage { get; set; }
    public int StageId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And a Stage class:

```
public class Stage
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int StageId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public long Ticks { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public TimeSpan Span
    {
        get { return TimeSpan.FromTicks(Ticks); }
    }

    // Make sure that these stages are generated accordingly
    public static class Ids
    {
        // Zero
        public const int One = 1;
        // Ten Seconds
        public const int Two = 2;
        // One Minute
    }

}
```

In my repository service I have an AddCard method:

```
public Card AddCard(Card card)
    {
        int parentId = 0;
        Set parentSet = null;
        if (card.ParentSetId.HasValue)
        {
            parentId = card.ParentSetId.Value;
            parentSet = GetSet(parentId);
        }

        card.ParentSet = parentSet;
        card.ParentSetId = parentSet.SetId;

        card.StageId = Stage.Ids.One;  // Set Id here with hopes of getting card.Stage to resolve as a nav property

        _db.Cards.Add(card);

        SaveChanges();

        return card;
    }
```

But for some reason, all of my Cards have a null value for Card.Stage - where Card.StageId is always some integer.  I'm trying to get the navigation property working so I can access properties of the Stage through a Card.

What have I done wrong here?

**Update:**

The property is null when I try to access them via my test.  First I create the card (in my test code):

```
 var cardDto = new CardDto  // Works!
            {
                Details = "Test Card",
            };
```

Then I send it to my Dto Service (also in test code):

```
 var fullCardDto = _service.AddCard(cardDto); // breaks because Stage is null when stageId is not
```

CardDto Class:

```
public class CardDto
{
    public CardDto(){}

    public CardDto(Card card)
    {
        CardId = card.CardId;
        Stage = card.Stage.Name;  // Fails here on its way back - creating the initial DTO works
        Details = card.Details;
    }

    [Key]
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = true)]
    public int CardId { get; set; }


    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = true)]
    public string Stage { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = false)]
    public string Details { get; set; }

    public Card ToEntity()
    {
        var newCard = new Card
            {
             CardId = CardId,
             Details = Details,
            };
        return newCard;
}
```

_service is DTO service:

```
public CardDto AddCard(CardDto card)
    {
        return new CardDto(_repository.AddCard(card.ToEntity()));
    }
```

`_repository` code is above.

This works all the way through the _repository call, but if I debug the _repository.AddCard method, StageId has a value after I call SaveChanges(), but Stage does not.

The Card is passed back up the chain until it's supposed to be converted to a Dto again, where it fails due to the null Stage.

What's odd is that this code works outside of the test - if I use a client to hit AddCard, I get a card back without any errors.

Comment: Did you check the Database data ? Does it have the  StageId value for Card ?

Comment: OK ,then have you enabled lazy loading or are you using Include? How do you retrieve the Stage?

Comment: I haven't disabled it and no, no include.  Stage is accessed via Ids as shown in the code above.  Am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: can you show me the code where the Stage is null when you access it?

Comment: @Jayantha Oh!  Yes, posting now

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31903/discussion-between-jayantha-and-sb2055)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make Lazy loading to work you need to have a proxy created. If you are loading Card though
the EF you will automatically received a object wrapped in a proxy object. You can do two things here
1. To you use lazy loading you can create a proxy like this,

```
public Card AddCard(Card card)
    {
        var cardProxy= _db.Cards.Create(); 
        //and copy all values from card to cardProxy here..
        int parentId = 0;
        Set parentSet = null;
        if (cardProxy.ParentSetId.HasValue)
        {
            parentId = cardProxy.ParentSetId.Value;
            parentSet = GetSet(parentId);
        }
        cardProxy.ParentSet = parentSet;
        cardProxy.ParentSetId = parentSet.SetId;

        cardProxy.StageId = Stage.Ids.One;  // Set Id here with hopes of getting card.Stage to resolve as a nav property

          SaveChanges();

        return cardProxy;
}
```

1. Or you can use explicit loading,

   public Card AddCard(Card card)
           {
               int parentId = 0;
               Set parentSet = null;
               if (card.ParentSetId.HasValue)
               {
                   parentId = card.ParentSetId.Value;
                   parentSet = GetSet(parentId);
               }

   ```
           card.ParentSet = parentSet;
           card.ParentSetId = parentSet.SetId;

           card.StageId = Stage.Ids.One;  // Set Id here with hopes of getting card.Stage to resolve as a nav property

           _db.Cards.Add(card);

           SaveChanges();

           context.Entry(card).Reference(p => p.Stage).Load();//load stage here

          return card;
       }
   ```

Comment: Thank you SO much.  I just posted something on your blog.